# Test data creation using RDBMS database?

Tags: mysql, database, mariadb

I am trying to create some TEST DATA, meaning fake data for playing around with MariaDB tables and databases.

I need to create some fake random data using SQL RDBMS. So, why not use Mockaroo.com , but on that website I can only do 1000 rows at one time. Which is extremely time consuming.

How can I create random fake data. Tons of it. For example, Let us say I want 2 millions rows of random data with ID, NAME, ADDRESS, PHONE, EMAIL.

Comment: Write a script in a language like PHP that generates random data and inserts it into the database.

Comment: Which language are you writing in?

Comment: @Barmar, I don't know PHP, What about writing SQL programming code?

Comment: @peregrine42 Don't know any language. Where can I start?

Comment: Enroll in a computer programming class.

Comment: Or hire a programmer. It's not something you just pick up quickly.

Comment: @Barmar I wish I had the money for it. Tuition is super duper expensive. I am looking for a open source way.

Comment: There's no magical way we can teach you how to program in the comment section here. SO is not a replacement for learning how to program. It's a place for programmers to get help from other programmers in fixing their code, not getting people to do it for you for free.

Comment: I like https://www.mockaroo.com, great service!

Comment: @Barmar Not asking for do it for me. I am asking if there is another way to create multiple sets of data.

Comment: Why don't you load some of the existing sample databases for MySQL?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

YES,

you can do it very easy with MariaDB:

The is a sequence Engine, thats what you need.

**Here a sample**

This Sample will store the data (created with the SELECT) in the table "yourtable".

```
INSERT INTO yourtable
SELECT seq,CONCAT('NAME FROM:',seq), CONCAT('ADR:',seq), CAST(RAND(SEQ)*10000000 AS INT),CONCAT(seq,'@dumymail.xx') FROM seq_1_to_1000000;
```

this will generate like this:

```
MariaDB [mysql]> SELECT seq,CONCAT('NAME FROM:',seq), CONCAT('ADR:',seq), CAST(RAND(SEQ)*10000000 AS INT),CONCAT(seq,'@dumymail.xx') FROM seq_1_to_10;
+-----+--------------------------+--------------------+---------------------------------+----------------------------+
| seq | CONCAT('NAME FROM:',seq) | CONCAT('ADR:',seq) | CAST(RAND(SEQ)*10000000 AS INT) | CONCAT(seq,'@dumymail.xx') |
+-----+--------------------------+--------------------+---------------------------------+----------------------------+
|   1 | NAME FROM:1              | ADR:1              |                         4054035 | 1@dumymail.xx              |
|   2 | NAME FROM:2              | ADR:2              |                         6555866 | 2@dumymail.xx              |
|   3 | NAME FROM:3              | ADR:3              |                         9057698 | 3@dumymail.xx              |
|   4 | NAME FROM:4              | ADR:4              |                         1559529 | 4@dumymail.xx              |
|   5 | NAME FROM:5              | ADR:5              |                         4061360 | 5@dumymail.xx              |
|   6 | NAME FROM:6              | ADR:6              |                         6563191 | 6@dumymail.xx              |
|   7 | NAME FROM:7              | ADR:7              |                         9065022 | 7@dumymail.xx              |
|   8 | NAME FROM:8              | ADR:8              |                         1566853 | 8@dumymail.xx              |
|   9 | NAME FROM:9              | ADR:9              |                         4068684 | 9@dumymail.xx              |
|  10 | NAME FROM:10             | ADR:10             |                         6570515 | 10@dumymail.xx             |
+-----+--------------------------+--------------------+---------------------------------+----------------------------+
10 rows in set (0.00 sec)

MariaDB [mysql]>
```

Comment: @Barmar Missed the first comment. :)

Comment: @MasterYoda What do you think `INSERT INTO yourtable` does?

Comment: yes, i wrote it a begin of my answer: try **INSERT into theTable SELECT ...... from seq_1_to_1000. so the selected data will store in the table

Comment: @BerndBuffen Thanks!  :-)

Comment: @Barmar Thanks :-)

Comment: @Master Yoda - Yes it the BEST. try to use the newest Version 10.1.14 of MariaDB. There are many many genial things direct in it. it also includes MariaDB Galera Cluster. its a Multi Master Cluster. And it works very fine and is easy to configure. see also MaxScale for DB Proxy